# Unresolved external symbol AES_set_encrypt_key when linking Rust code to boringssl on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, rust

I'm trying to compile my library wrapper of boringssl. I've compiled the crypto.lib file that definitely contains the symbol `AES_set_encrypt_key`, judging by the command:

```
nm crypto.lib --demangle
```

Then I've generated a FFI file that declares that symbol:

```
use std::os::raw::{c_char, c_int, c_uchar, c_uint, c_void};

#[repr(C)]
pub struct aes_key_st {
    pub rd_key: [u32; 60usize],
    pub rounds: c_uint,
}

pub type AES_KEY = aes_key_st;

extern "C" {
    pub fn AES_set_encrypt_key(key: *const u8, bits: c_uint, aeskey: *mut AES_KEY) -> c_int;
    pub fn foo() -> c_int;
}
```

Here are the original C declarations:

```c
struct aes_key_st {
  uint32_t rd_key[4 * (AES_MAXNR + 1)];
  unsigned rounds;
};

typedef struct aes_key_st AES_KEY;

OPENSSL_EXPORT int AES_set_encrypt_key(const uint8_t *key, unsigned bits, AES_KEY *aeskey);
```

build.rs:

```
fn main() {
    let out_dir = "<path_to_lib>"
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", out_dir);
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=crypto");
}
```

I am getting an `LNK2019 (unresolved external symbol)` error when compiling this code.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had compiled my library with 32-bit version of MSVC, but Rust compiles programs with 64-bit one. That's why there was a conflict.